# Remove lines of code from multiple files

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm running a Web Server in a Virtual Box for testing some projects.
And I noticed that some of the html files have this unwanted lines. 
I want these lines of code from multiple html/htm files removed so I did it like this:

```
find /Desktop/TEST_REMOVAL3/ -name '*.html' -or -name '*.htm' -or -name '*.php' | sed -i "/<SCRIPT Language=VBScript>/,/ //--></SCRIPT><!-- /d"
```

So far, the 1st part where if looks/finds all html files works. The part where I need to remove the lines starting from `<SCRIPT Language=VBS>` to `</SCRIPT>` using `sed` fails :D

I'll try to figure it out again while waiting for your suggestions and scolding on where I went wrong :D

Comment: Close voters: This question is not off-topic! Questions about shell scripting and bash are *perfectly* fine here as long as the OP is running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the file list from `find` as arguments for the `sed` command (instead as imput, which is what your line is doing), you have to use either the `xargs` command:

```
find dir -name '*.html' | xargs -d \\n sed -i "COMMANDS"
```

In which case `xargs` takes the file list, using newline (`\n`) as separator between file names and starts `sed` with them as arguments.

Or you use the `-exec` option of find:

```
find dir -name '*.html' -exec sed -i "COMMANDS" {} +
```

In which case `find` will run the command between `-exec` and `+` while replacing `{}` with (a list of) file names. There is also

```
find dir -name '*.html' -exec sed -i "COMMANDS" {} \;
```

which does essentially the same, but starts a new `sed` for every single file name.

Comment: Also, simplify your sed statements and use single quotes , sed -i '/VBScript/,/SCRIPT>/d' , you do not need to match the entire line